# Using rotativa in Asp.net Core 1.0 app but not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-to-pdf, rotativa

I want to use `Rotativa` in my application, but when I include `"Rotativa` in my `project.json` file. The package console shows `Restoring packages failed` and the error is:

> The Dependency Rotativa 1.6.4 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

If Rotativa is not available in ASP Core, is there any other way to convert my page to pdf?

Comment: Make sure you are using the version built specifically for Asp Core.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa.NetCore/

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the **proper package**, remove `Rotativa` from your project and install `Rotativa.AspNetCore`, your app will work just fine after that!

AspCore is not AspNet, make sure to always use `Core` packages